# using python 3 urllib to access website but failed

Tags: python, http

I am trying to use the below code to access websites in python 3 using urllib

```
url = "http://www.goal.com"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}  

r = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers)  
urllib.request.urlopen(r).read(1000)
```

It works fine when it access "yahoo.com", but it always returned error 403 when accessing sites such as "goal.com, hkticketing.com.hk" and I cannot figure out what I am missing.  Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Seems to be working for me; can you show the output you're getting?

Comment: Sorry I just used another computer to run and it is fine now, probably becoz I am using cloud python (www.pythonanywhere.com) and some website refuse its connection?

Comment: The Python web consoles usually restrict network access; otherwise people would use them to do bad stuff.

Comment: This addresses your exact issue: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/403ForbiddenError

Comment: If you look at [PythonAnywhere's whitelist of sites accessible from free accounts](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/), you'll see that `.yahoo.com` is on there, while `goal.com` and `hkticketing.com.hk` are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 2.x version , you can use urllib2 to fetch the contents. You can invoke the add headers function to add the header information. Then invoke the open method and read the contents. Finally print them.

```
import urllib2
import sys

print sys.version
url = urllib2.build_opener()
url.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0')]
print url.open('http://hkticketing.com.hk').read()
```